# Mapping a grayscale image into a weighted undirected graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I am looking for a method to convert an image into a network.
I have found the study Z. Wu, X. Lu, Y. Deng, Image edge detection
based on local dimension: A complex networks approach. Physica A
(2015), http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2015.07.020

In this paper a model for mapping a grayscale image into weighted
undirected network is proposed. This model is based on the weighted
combination of the Euclidean distance and gray-level similarity
between pixels. In the proposed model, pixels and relationships between
them in the image are respectively regarded as nodes and edges in the
network. The value of Euclidean distance $d$ of the two pixels defines
whether there is or not an edge between corresponding nodes:
$$e(p_{xy}, p_{x_0y_0}) = \{\exists, d \le R; \not \exists, d>R\}, (1)$$
$R$ is radius (integer parameter of model).
The weight of corresponding edge defines by the balance compromise between
the Euclidean distance and the absolute value of gray-level similarity
of two pixels:
$$w_e =\sqrt{(α|g_p − g_{p_0}|)^2 + (βd)^2}, (2)$$
where α and β are the scaling parameters of gray-level difference and Euclidean distance respectively, $g_p$ and $g_{p_0}$ are graylevel of pixels $p(x, y)$ and $p(x_0, y_0)$ respectively.

For given image with pixel set $P = \{p_1, p_2, ... , p_n\}$, the node set of corresponding weighted undirected network $G = (V, E)$ is $V = \{v_1, v_2, ... , v_n\}$. And the edge set $E = \{e_1, e_2, ... , e_m\}$ can be calculated by Eqs. (1) and (2).

The Euclidean distance $d$ Eq. (1) defines whether there is or not
an edge between corresponding nodes. Therefore, a graph has the
constant topology (the number of nodes and edges) for any grayscale
images with equal sizes ($n$ times $m$ pixels). Or I'm wrong?

Could anyone please give me an idea how to take into account the
gray-level similarity of pixels in order to mapping a grayscale image
into weighted undirected network?